# Angular 6 dom-to-image throws uncaught error (Can't convert html to image)

Tags: javascript, angular, image, wkhtmltoimage

I want to convert html section into image(**Note** Html section has many other images from server)
I am using angular 6 and node.js and library for converting html to image is 
 [dom-to-img](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dom-to-image)

> **It is working in localhost** But when I test it into Production level it gives me error That is in picture
>   [image: Error]

Here is HTML Area that I want to convert into an image in which signature and back blue color coming from the server as URL

[image: Html Area]

i used  **@ViewChild('checkContainer') container;** to get dom(Html section) reference
and then i'm calling a function that gives me an image type file and I pass to the server that saves this image in Database.
**All is working in Localhost but not in production**

> Here is the code I have tried.

```
async convertToImage(fileName) {
try {
  const blob = await domtoimage.toBlob(this.container.nativeElement);
   this.checkImageFile = new File([blob], fileName + '.png', {
     type: 'image/png'
   }); // image File
} catch (error) {
  console.log('ops error', error);
}
```

}

and above function will call from this function **checkImageFile** is property name that is declared in my file.

```
async addCheck() {
const fileName = this.checkModel.checkNumber;
await this.convertToImage(fileName);
if (this.checkImageFile) {
  console.log(this.checkImageFile);
} else {
  console.log('dom to image is not working properly');
}
```

}

What is missing in my code? can you please help me?
Thank you all
Happy Coding.:)

Comment: can you please avoid adding code as a picture!
 and clarify  where you are calling this convertToImage function

Comment: yes sir i am editing my question

Comment: how are you import the  dom-to-img lib ?!

Comment: I have installed from this command **npm i dom-to-image**
and import on the top of file like

``import domtoimage from 'dom-to-image'; ``

Comment: I think this is a compatibility error with this lib because the error is coming from the js polyfills, I checked its repo and it some like a cave,  nobody answers the issues from about 2 years ago. 
put actully no issues with angular 6  found so I recommend you to checkout this lib https://www.npmjs.com/package/dom-to-image-more

Comment: okay try to use 
`import * as domtoimage from 'dom-to-image';`

Comment: Thanks I will try that library and hope for best :) 
Thank you again.

Comment: you are welcome, let me know if it works for you

Comment: @TawfiekKhalaf Thank you for this package  npmjs.com/package/dom-to-image-more
it worked for me but it changes the font of html section
But this package **npm html-to-image** did great work for me 
Thank you again :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a compatibility issue with this package you can use the following package instead [dom-to-image-more](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dom-to-image-more)

Comment: Same issue with 'dom-to-image-more' package as well.  Could not find a declaration file for module 'dom-to-image-more'